# How to change the format of a column in GridView web application

Tags: c#, web

How to change the format of a column in GridView from c#

```
        Label lblDate= (Label)(e.Row.FindControl("lblDate"));
        if (lblDate!= null)
        {
            lblDate.Text = (string)DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "event_start");
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by format change? You want to display a date-time on one of the column of your gridview?

Answer (score 0):

On the `<asp:BoundField>` element of your grid view, set `DataFormatString="xxx"`

where "xxx" is your format string. e.g. `DataFormatString="{0:C}"` will format as a currency with the default currency symbol, and 2 decimals etc.

Just check the MSDN help for BoundField.DataFormatString for all the standard formatting options.